# Java: JDialog Closing Issue

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

In this program i'm facing two problems when i close the `JDialog` the dialog doesn't close properly like `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.And how to give title to this dialog.
Code

```
public class Dialog extends JDialog{

    public Dialog(){

        setSize(300,200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Main Method

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Dialog frame = new Dialog();

    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Are you sure you want to exit the application? ",
                    "EXIT Application", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                System.exit(0);

            else if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            }

        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: 1) `setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` 2)      `setTitle("Dialog");`

Comment: @LuxxMiner but DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE close the dialog slowly not like EXIT_ON_CLOSE and what does it mean DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE

Comment: `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` shuts down your whole program, `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` just removes the dialog, in this case. It's not like calling `setVisible(false)`, because you can't use the same dialog anymore after disposing it.

Comment: @LuxxMiner Is there a way that i can Close the whole program in JDialog

Comment: A `WindowListener` overriding the `windowClosing` method can achieve that by calling `System.exit(0);` inside it. There is no `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` for a JDialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> not like EXIT_ON_CLOSE

`EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is not supported for a JDialog.

> but DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE close the dialog slowly

It closes the dialog immediately and focus will go back to the parent JFrame.

> Is there a way that i can Close the whole program in JDialog

You need to close the frame.

Maybe you are trying to close the application from a popup dialog? If so then check out [Closing an Application](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/).

It will show you how to:

1. Use a WindowListener to handle `windowClosing` and display a popup dialog, or
2. use the suggested class to make the coding easier.

Comment: but it is showing window closing for JFrame but i want to manipulate with JDialog

Comment: @JohnDoe A `Dialog` still extends `Window`, so you can also add a `WindowListener` to your dialog.

Comment: @LuxxMiner and camickr thanks both of you for your answers

Comment: @JohnDoe You can't just convert a `JDialog` to a `JFrame`... Try `System.exit(0)` to shut down the program completely.

Comment: @JohnDoe, you miss the whole point of this answer. An application should have a single main JFrame. Then you use a JDialog as child windows as needed. A normal JDialog will just close itself, not the entire application. So my suggestion here is that you are trying to use a "confirmation dialog" asking the user to confirm closing of the app. So you need a JFrame and then when the user clicks the close button, the JOptionPane (which is a custom JDialog) will display. If the user clicks yes then the dialog will close and the application will exit.

Comment: @camickr I edited my question now its working fine but does it is bad code

Comment: @JohnDoe, I have already stated you should not be using a JDialog as the single window in your application. A JDialog does not appear in the task bar so if you lose focus on the dialog the only way to get it back is to tab through all the windows which is not very user friendly. So yes I would consider this bad code. Also, "Dialog" is an AWT class so your class name is confusing. There is no need to even create a class just to set a couple of properties.

Comment: @camickr but i want to clear my concept about it and this dialog is just for only user password dialog when user enter correct credentials the frame will be appear

Comment: @JohnDoe *" this dialog is just for only user password dialog when user enter correct credentials the frame will be appear"* - Why don't you set the default close operation to dispose then? You don't need to shut down your whole program to open another frame, just dispose the dialog.

Comment: @JohnDoe, Create a frame with a "login panel". When the login is successful, remove the login panel and add your "application panel". Again, the problem with a dialog is that it can lose focus and it is not easy to get back. Otherwise use the suggestion of LuxxMiner above. There is no need to exit the JVM.